# Find $a,b$ such that Rolle's Theorem is true for $f$ in the $[a,b]$ interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f(x)=3-e^{-x}, \forall x \in\mathbb R$. I am asked to find $a,b$ such that Rolle's theorem can be implemented for $f$ in the $[a,b]$ interval.

Rolle's theorem states that if $f$ in continuous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $\exists ξ\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(ξ)=0$.
My try is: Let $a,b$ be random numbers $\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, then $f$ is continious and differentiable in R, so is in $[a,b]$ as well, so $\existsξ\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(ξ)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e^ξ}=0 $ which is absurd. So there is no $a,b\in R$ such that Rolle's Theorem can be implemented for $f$. Is this correct, or am I mistaken? Thanks!

Comment: Seems fine to me. Another way would be to show that for all $f(a)=f(b)$ it follows $a=b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct though it used the contrapositive of the Rolles's theorem.

**Rolle's Theorem**: $(A\land B\land C)\implies D$

**Contrapositive**: $\lnot D\implies\lnot(A\land B\land C)$

or $\lnot D\implies (\lnot A\lor\lnot B\lor\lnot C)$

where $A: f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

$B: f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$

$C: f(a)=f(b)$

$D: \exists c\in (a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$.

**If the statement $S$ is true then so it is contrapositive.**